# Nullable DateTime and Dapper Dot Net

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, dapper

I have a Type with a nullable DateTime column. When I try to use Dapper Dot Net to create a collection of that Type, I run into problems.

**Scenario 1**: If **all** the rows **are null** for this column it's fine

**Scenario 2**: If **one or more** the rows **have a date value** for this column, I get the following error:

> Error parsing column 3 (LastCompleted=2013-12-03 00:00:00 - DateTime)
>   - Invalid cast from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

It's probably **worth noting** that I am using Dapper in a .NET 3.5 repository library - which seems to be fine, except for this issue.

If this is a known issue, then no problem, but I can't find anything specifically relating to Nullable DateTime in Dapper.

Comment: You've come to the right place, Dapper backs StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Ha yeah :) So fingers crossed....

Comment: Just an update if anybody ever reads this. I've had to give up on Nullable DateTime with Dapper. It works *sometimes*. I errors *sometimes*. And nobody is answering...

Comment: I'm looking on the Dapper site now to see what issues are around... can't see anything as yet. Usually Marc Gravell takes these questions.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Thanks Adam. Would be interesting to see if Marc or anybody picks this up.

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce the behaviour you are describing with no success -- just to to be sure, may you show us some code?